# Display clicked K2 Article on new page, and not on page you already are

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

My website works with a main menu whose tabs are directly linked to K2 Articles / Categories of K2 Articles. The article(s) all nicely show if a given menu tab is chosen, BUT when an article is opened, that article opens up on the same page you already are, instead of opening on a separate site, with only the article's content (and general stuff as main menu, etc.) displayed.

How can I configure Joomla to show up clicked K2 Articles on new and not on the same page ?

To be more illustrative; imagine the following page layout (which works):

[image]

Now let's say you click on the first article ("K2 Article 1"). Then, what happens is the following (same happens for all the other articles of course):

[image]

So the article is displayed on the same page, below the title image and the introductory text of the page. I however want an article to be displayed like that if someone clicks on it (on a new page, getting rid of the title image and the intro text to display an article, as below):

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Can we see a screenshot? Have you tried contacting K2? See how I added relevant tags to your previous post? We want you to work ALL of your posted questions toward a system-resolution.  If a question doesn't receive any support, edit it to include more relevant details.  If you manage to self-solve, you can resolve your own question by posting a complete and educational answer, then awarding it the green tick.

Comment: You want your menu items to send the user to "a separate site"?  You can improve your question by clarifying the current issue and your desired result.  Questions that gain upvotes generally show research effort, at least one attempt to self-solve, and are crystal clear about what needs solving.